# regex to ignore lines with specific symbol

Tags: regex, relative-path, regex-lookarounds, absolute-path

I'm trying to get a regex to set change relative paths to absolute with an alias, and ignore any lines with alias already indicated with the @ symbol to prevent folder/file name matches.  I've got as far as the replace and match , but I can't do the ignore lines with @ bit.  I would also like it to match  the /foldername/ forward slashes either side when selecting.

[image: RegEx JP]

https://regex101.com/r/vRUegE/1/

I would have expected the lines with @ to be ignored

***Here is the correct response thanks to Wiktor:***

[image: Perfect working screenshot]

[Working example](https://regex101.com/r/aOuFtc/1)

Using a combination of [WinGrep](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grepwin/) and these regex's it was easy to refactor hundreds of paths in hundreds of files in minutes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a [*negative lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!@)` after the positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=from..)(?!@)(.*)(?=module)(.*)(module)
           ^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LLU4z9/1). The `(?!@)` will fail the match once `@` is found right after `from` and any 2 chars immediately to the right of it.

Note that the regex might need further adjusting as `(?=module)` does not make much sense here. You might as well use [`(?<=from..)(?!@)(.*)(module)`](https://regex101.com/r/LLU4z9/2).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor.  So far I've settled on (?<=from..)(?!@)(.*)(\/module\/) which also includes the folder forward slashes.  In the area that get's removed is there a way to ensure only dot and forward slash is the only content otherwise ignore the line too??

Comment: Sorry, what is the example path to ignore? `import { service9 } from ".23455./module/8.service";`? Try [`(?<=from..)(?!@)([\/.]*)(\/module\/)`](https://regex101.com/r/LLU4z9/3).

Comment: For example: import { service11 } from "dontinclude/../module/11.service";  If the dontinclude was .. it would be okay

Comment: Perfect Wiktor [link](https://regex101.com/r/aOuFtc/1)   Reg Ex: **(?<=from..)(?!@)([\/.]*)(\/module\/)**

Comment: I have a similar smaller issue here, can't get it to ignore a certain line: [Reg ex not ignoring spec files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154817/reg-ex-to-ignore-spec-ts-files-for-aot-angular-5-build)

Comment: @MagicLuckyCat See my comment to that question. Please remove it here.

Answer (score 1):

difficult to say in which language you do it, seem java , regexp is bit different for different languages .

```
(?<=from..)(.*)(?=module)(.*(module)/g
```

here you refer (.*) - e.q. any repeat chars , you need to change to

```
([^\@]*)  ( or ([^@]*)   )
```

e.q. any non @ char