# Reg ex to ignore .spec.ts files for AOT angular 5 build

Tags: regex, angular, configuration, jasmine, aot

Angular 5 ngtools isn't ignoring all ".spec.ts" files in my production build.

**How would I exclude **.spec.ts* but keep any other *.ts* ?**

> /(?:.ngfactory.js|.ngstyle.js|.ts)$/

**From my webpack.prod.config.js...**

```
module.exports = merge(baseConfig, {
    devtool: "source-map",
     module: {
         rules:
         [
            {   // AOT mode support for production
                test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                loader: '@ngtools/webpack'
            }
        ]
    },
```

[Click here on link example of image to regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lgOa1A/1/)

[image]

Comment: Try [`^(?!.*\.spec\.ts$).*\.ts$`](https://regex101.com/r/jvEzTB/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to allow files with `.ngfactory.js`, `.ngstyle.js` and `.ts` extensions, that means you need to match any string ending with these extensions and not ending with `.spec.ts`.

Use

```
/^(?!.*\.spec\.ts$).*(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jvEzTB/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\.spec\.ts$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (`.*`) and then `.spec.ts` at the end of the string (`$`) immediately to the right of the current location
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)` - `.ngfactory.js`, `.ngstyle.js` or `.ts`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I'd just managed to scrape together:  (?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$(?<!\.spec\.ts)$   Thanks @Wiktor!!

Comment: @magic JS regex engine doesn't support lookbehinds, you have to use a lookahead anchored at the start of thestring.